# How to expand the pivot column groups by default in angular ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using angular ag-grid to display my data. I want to expand the pivot column group by default and hide the expand and collapse icon for the pivot column.
I have created a demo under this link "https://plnkr.co/edit/Qkyrcrpemy9dyxqW" Could anyone please tell me how can I achieve it.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the property `suppressExpandablePivotGroups` to `true` on your grid. This will make your pivot columns fixed. See [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/pivoting/#fixed-pivot-column-groups) for documentaion.

[Updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CHW4H3o54Qc50RqF).